# MySQL Query in Discord.js returns "unkown"

Tags: mysql, discord

I've improved my code a lot over the past few days but I'm finally stuck. My query is returning "unknown". I've attached the code and a screenshot of the database. I'm trying to use the discordid to pull the correspnding info from the hfuid column. I would greatly appreciate a point in the right direction (Looking for video tutorials preferably).

```html
  if (command == "hf") {
    connection.connect();
    connection.query("SELECT hfuid FROM cleaamwd_hfbot.users WHERE discorduid = 242037588586659850", function(err, rows) {
      message.reply(rows);
      connection.end();
    })
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This query would work to get the date from the cell you need

```js
if (command === "hf") {
    connection.connect();
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM cleaamwd_hfbot.users WHERE discorduid = '242037588586659850'", (err, rows) {
        if (err) throw err;
        const hfuid = rows[0].hfuid
        message.reply(hfuid);
    })
    connection.end();
}
```